# Variation of Jeep problem, don't know how to minimize the fuel?

Tags: mathematics

> You have a car that has a tank that can store $1$ unit of fuel. You need to get to a destination $1.5$ units of distance away. The car travels $1$ unit of distance on $1$ unit of fuel. You can deposit fuel along the route, but capacity is never more than $1$ unit.  What is the minimum amount of fuel you need to make the trip?

**My attempts at a solution**: a solution would have the car having $1$ unit of fuel at $0.5$ metres equal. So it is not making any unnecessary returns. So the problem can be reduced to the minimum amount of fuel required to transport $1$ unit of fuel a distance of $0.5$.

I know it should be about $2-2.9$ units. Here is a drawing of using $2.9$ units:

[image]

Is there a way to optimize this?

***Edit***: I cannot see how this is the same as the camel problem, because the camel problem would give an answer of $3$, when $2.9$ is possible.

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/230/a-camel-transporting-bananas could be related even though i dont understand the question.

Comment: @Oray I have seen the camel problem, I think it is related, but slightly different (I may have misunderstood), I feel it is an amalgamation of that and the [jeep problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_problem), where you have to go back to the base every trip, and the camel problem where you are trying to maximise the amount you bring a set distance.

Comment: You cannot get to 1.5 from .2 with a 1 tank

Comment: @paparazzo You can, but you need to deposite 0.4 unit of fuel at 0.5 unit of distance, and come back to take the 0.9 fuel left at 0.2 distance

Comment: i am pretty sure that this type of question is asked before, cant find it.

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17156/how-much-water-do-you-need-to-cross-the-desert this is it i guess

Comment: @Oray, I still don't get how this is the camel problem, then what is the answer, the camel problem gives 3 when I can give an example of 2.9??

Comment: How does this differ from the classic definition of the Jeep problem, as explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_problem (the 'crossing the desert' variant)?

Comment: Your 2.9 is wrong. When you reach distance 0.2, you can only filling your tank up to 1. So your car will stop at distance 1.2.

Comment: @jsm, so what is the answer then, 3?

Comment: @athin, don't see how it is wrong

Comment: @JimSi On your third trip, at distance 0.2, you have a 0.7 unit from the station and you have put a 1.2 fuel in your cache. Your filling tank won't be enough to take that 1.9 fuel!

Comment: @Untitpoi Im not suggesting to fill it all up when at 0.7 and 1.2 cache, I suggest to take 0.3 from the cache, then go to a distance of 0.5, go back and pick up the rest. See this image , I have drawn out, , really do not get it. https://ibb.co/kxCwm7

Comment: @JimSi you're right, you should add that in your question! I guess it could be optmized though.

Comment: @athin, see my drawing.

Comment: yep2 saw that, nicely done! :D

Comment: If you are going to answer then hide it and write it up in text.

Comment: @JimSi this is not camel problem though it is the same question as water problem :) only difference is yours is 1.5 units, that question is 2 units.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first of all, this is a classic [Jeep Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JeepProblem.html) but it's inverted: instead of given how many fuel then maximize the distance, we are given the distance and minimize the fuel.

Actually on above link, there is a formula to calculate this:

> Given $n + f$ units of fuel (where $0 \le f \lt 1$), the maximum distance will be: $$ \frac{f}{2n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2i-1}}$$

*(Honestly, I can't prove that formula tho...)*

Continuing on:

> Using only $2$ units of fuels ($n = 2$ and $f = 0$) won't reach $1.5$ units of distance since the maximum distance will be: $$ \frac{0}{5} + (\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{3}) = 1\frac{1}{3} \approx 1.333$$

Because OP has proven that we can use less than $3$ units of fuels, then:

> $n$ must be $2$ and we have to find $f$ such that: $$ \frac{f}{5} + (\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{3}) = 1.5$$
>  Turns out, the $f$ is $\frac{5}{6}$ so we need $2\frac{5}{6} \approx 2.833$ units of fuels in total.

In practice, to prove it's possible:

> Suppose we divide $1.5$ units of distance to $4$ points like this.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Then do the following:
>  - Take $1$ units of fuels on $A$.
>  - Go to $B$, put $4/6$ units of fuels, go back to $A$.
>  - Take $1$ units of fuels on $A$.
>  - Go to $B$, take $1/6$ units of fuels on $B$.
>  - Go to $C$, put $1/3$ units of fuels, go back to $B$.
>  - Take $1/6$ units of fuels on $B$, go back to $A$.
>  - Take $5/6$ units of fuels on $A$.
>  - Go to $B$, take $2/6$ units of fuels on $B$.
>  - Go to $C$, take $1/3$ units of fuels on $C$.
>  - Go to $D$.

Comment: this answered my confusion perfectly, It is deceptively quite tricky and the reverse as you say. I guess deriving the formula would be the last piece.

Comment: I'm afraid the proof for the formula is "too math" for this puzzling site.. or it isn't? I may give some "greedy" observation but still can't prove it is indeed the optimal atm.

Answer (score 0):

I think 3 tanks

> [**S**][0][0][0][0][0][**E**]
>  travel 1/4 and leave 1/2 tank
>  [**S**][½][0][0][0][0][**E**]
>  travel 1/4 top off then travel 1/4 and leave 1/4
>  [**S**][¼][¼][0][0][0][**E**]
>  travel 1/4 top off then travel 1/4 and top off the travel 1 to destination

Comment: On the second trip, you could also top up in *both* directions and leave more fuel at the turn-around point - this would mean 1 less top-up on the third trip

Comment: @Chronocidal I don't follow.  Nice edit.